# Not found page blocked via robots.txt still gets click/impression

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt, impressions

Some dummy pages comes with template had been indexed early. Those are completely removed and blocked via robots.txt two month ago but we can still see those pages showing under Search Analytics in Webmaster Tools and has 2 impression last week.

[image]

How it possible? If anyone (probably inhouse developers when testing) visit to broken link, does it count as impression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not found page blocked via robots.txt still gets click/impression

Your graph shows 0 clicks - so it's not getting any clicks. An "impression" on the other hand is simply when this URL has appeared somewhere in the search results, regardless of whether anyone has *clicked* on it. So it would appear this *URL* is still indexed. From the [Google Help docs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7042828?hl=en):

> **What is an impression?**
>   A link URL records an impression when it appears in a search result for a user. Whether or not the link must actually be scrolled into view or otherwise visible depends on the type of search element that contains the link

---

> Those are completely removed and blocked via robots.txt two month ago

Blocking a URL in `robots.txt` does not necessarily prevent that URL from being indexed and returned in the SERPs, particularly if it is linked to from other sources. And if it was already indexed *before* being blocked then it is likely to remained indexed for a considerable length of time. Note here we are talking about the URL itself being indexed and not necessarily the *content* (since that is now blocked by `robots.txt`).

To specifically *remove* a URL from the Google index then you should return a 410 Gone and optionally use the URL removal tool, rather than block with `robots.txt`.